# Calculating Checksum for transaction-builder.json

Tags: gnosis-safe

I'm working on revising the Balancer Governance process.  Part of this is asking proposal posters to prepare Safe transaction builder json exports using the safe UI and submit them as part of the governance process and before a vote is taken.

In the end we process 10-20 items a week, most of which are agains the same multisig, so we are working to write a script to merge a set of jsons based on the target safe.

That's all easy/fine.  The only real issue is this checksum here in the metadata:

```
  "meta": {
    "name": "Transactions Batch",
    "description": "",
    "txBuilderVersion": "1.11.1",
    "createdFromSafeAddress": "0xc38c5f97B34E175FFd35407fc91a937300E33860",
    "createdFromOwnerAddress": "",
    "checksum": "0x2278322fc7e9159d3d46832c1866c94311186dd9920f6d31c15af0242f0f4e35"
  },
```

So now my questions.

1: Is this checksum field required, and if so how can one calculate it?
2: Is there somewhere I can find the source code and/or the docs for the transaction-builder app and/or who maintains it?

Answer (score 0):

The checksum is calculated by serializing the batch and hashing this with sha3. Here is the relevant section from the Gnosis Safe UI, which can be run as a script:

```js
const web3 = require('web3')

const stringifyReplacer = (_, value) => (value === undefined ? null : value)

const serializeJSONObject = (json) => {
  if (Array.isArray(json)) {
    return `[${json.map((el) => serializeJSONObject(el)).join(',')}]`
  }

  if (typeof json === 'object' && json !== null) {
    let acc = ''
    const keys = Object.keys(json).sort()
    acc += `{${JSON.stringify(keys, stringifyReplacer)}`

    for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
      acc += `${serializeJSONObject(json[keys[i]])},`
    }

    return `${acc}}`
  }

  return `${JSON.stringify(json, stringifyReplacer)}`
}

const calculateChecksum = (batchFile) => {
  const serialized = serializeJSONObject({
    ...batchFile,
    meta: { ...batchFile.meta, name: null },
  })
  const sha = web3.utils.sha3(serialized)

  return sha || undefined
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I also discovered that the batch will run even if the checksum is empty or incorrect.